# RuntimeError: Unimplemented: DNN library is not found

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, transformer-model, jax

I was trying to implement vision transformer by google and I came across this error during inference:

```
RuntimeError: Unimplemented: DNN library is not found.: while running replica 0 and partition 0 of a replicated computation (other replicas may have failed as well).
```

I followed [this](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/4920) post but it didn't help. What should I do?

Comment: Have you installed [cudnn](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/developer-guide/index.html)?

Comment: Yup, that worked